# R6Class bug __Deferred_Default_Marker__

Tags: r, oop, r6

I'm implementing a new R6Class and trying to add new members dynamically (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/R6/vignettes/Introduction.html#adding-members-to-an-existing-class) but I get this error **"__Deferred_Default_Marker__"** (whether it be dynamic or not) when I implement the getx2 function.

```
Simple <- R6Class("Simple",
                  public = list(
                     x = 1,
                     getx = function() self$x,
                     getx2 = function() return(self$x * 2)
                  )
)

# To replace an existing member, use overwrite=TRUE
Simple$set("public", "x", 10, overwrite = TRUE)

s <- Simple$new()
s$getx2() # this returns "__Deferred_Default_Marker__"
```

Any ideas on this? It's exactly like in the documentation

Comment: Your code works fine for me. What version of R6 are you using?

Comment: My version is 2.2.0

Comment: Same here. Try quitting and restarting R.

Comment: Now I'm trying to update to version 2.2.2 with "devtools::install_github('r-lib/R6', build_vignettes = FALSE)" but it tells me "namespace 'R6' is imported by 'CompatibilityAPI', 'mrsdeploy' so cannot be unloaded" ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to update the package. The problem with the following instruction:

```
devtools::install_github('r-lib/R6', build_vignettes = FALSE)
```

was it threw me the following error: `namespace 'R6' is imported by 'CompatibilityAPI', 'mrsdeploy' so cannot be unloaded"`

so i closed RStudio, and opened R.exe (`C:\Program Files\R\R-3.3.3\bin`) and ran the same command. Now, I have this package:

```
Package: R6
Version: 2.2.2.9000
URL: https://github.com/r-lib/R6/
```

and it works as in the specification.